# store ReactComponent in an object's property as a reference

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pass-by-reference, react-component

I'm trying to import icons as ReactComponents in ***keystones.ts***-

```
import {ReactComponent as IconUI} from '...'
```

I'm exporting these icons so that I could call them as, e.g. `<IconUI>` in another file.

```
export {IconUI, IconResponsiveness, ...}
```

But within the same ***keystones.ts*** file, I'd like to store these *'icon-components'* as properties in the objects inside `keystonesData`-

```
export const keystonesData : KeystoneType[] = [
    {
        heading: 'Keystone 1',
        detail: `Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic 
                 or web designs.`,
  /* want to render the icon while mapping keystonesData */
        icon: IconUI
    },
    ...
];
```

So in short, I want to render the icons in the mapping function like so-

```
keystonesData.map(({heading, detail, icon}) => {
  return (
    <icon />
  )
})
```

**The Problem** is that I cannot just store the `src` string because I need to render the icons as `ReactComponent`. So is there any way to somehow store the **reference** to these *'icon-components'*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you are importing the same icon but giving it a temporary name:

```
import {ReactComponent as IconUIWithoutSrc} from '...'
```

Now, you build the full icon, with its src, and you export the icon with the src provides as a functional component:

```
const IconUI = () => <IconUIWithoutSrc src="..." />
```

And then you can simply export the Icon while it is already holding the `src`.

```
export {IconUI, IconResponsiveness, ...}
```

And later...

```
keystonesData.map(({heading, detail, Icon}) => {
  return (
    <Icon />
  )
})
```

That should do the trick.